# multiple Windows Eventlog output array

Tags: powershell

I try to get the lockout event logs in an `array` to write each event log but this doesn't seem to work? Problem is, that i can't use `Get-EventLog` because I can't filter for the last 10 with a special ID

```
$lockout = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4740} -MaxEvents 10
$lockoutevent =Get-EventLog -Log Security | where {$_.EventID -eq 4740} | Format-List -Property Index

foreach ($event in $lockout)
{
    $eventXML = $event | ConvertTo-XML
    $Array = @($event.RecordId)
}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt 0; $i++)
{
    Get-EventLog -Index $Array[$i] -LogName Security | Format-List -Property *
}
```

Comment: So, your goal is to just get the 10 latest lockout events? Line 1 already accomplishes that, why add the rest?

Comment: Because I want to make a own output with the username and the time and it's not possible to extract them with Get-WinEvent. So I wanted to get the last 10 RecordID's so I can use them for the Get-EventLog and Index.

Comment: It's absolutely possible with just `Get-WinEvent`, each `$event` in `$lockout` already has all the information you need. For example `(([xml]$event.ToXml()).Event.EventData.Data |? Name -eq 'SubjectUserName').innerText` would give you the username